# Remote Debuging Perl, Dancer, Starman, Docker

Tags: perl, docker, debugging, dancer, starman

Hi stackoverflow users,

I am using:
 - Perl 
 - Dancer
 - Starman
 - Camelcade
 - Intellij

I built a container with the web application. I configure the environment variables requires by Camelcade.
when I run the debug:

- perl -d:Camelcadedb web.pl

It only debug the startup perl file, that calls Dancer and then finish there with Dancer and Starman running, but not all the web application is in debug mode, because when I invoke some endpoint it is not debugging.
My idea is when I invoke to URL and It has a break point, It stop there.
Someone can give an idea, what is going on ?

Comment: [Similar question about Mojolicious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013380/how-can-you-invoke-interactive-perl-debugging-with-hypnotoad-or-morbo)

Answer (score 1):

To MAP the application, the application folder in the server or container and in the machine that will act as debugger have to be in the same location, if not we can debug the application.
Do not forget to expose port in container.